# what's the '~!' function in awk

Tags: awk

I made a wrong type in awk and get a unexpected result.
So I got confused about this.

my passwd file has 39 line.

```
# wc -l /etc/passwd

39 /etc/passwd
```

now the '!~' in awk shows

```
# awk -F':' '$1 !~ /root/' /etc/passwd | wc -l

37
```

while the '~!' got a different result

```
# awk -F':' '$1 ~! /root/' /etc/passwd | wc -l

1
```

after that I deleted `wc` command to see which line it got

```
# awk -F':' '$1 ~! /root/' /etc/passwd

vbirduser1:x:1000:1001::/home/vbirduser1:/bin/bash
```

It's the first common user in my Linux.

So, what's the '~!' mean in awk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Comparison-Operators.html

> x !~ y True if the string x does not match the regexp denoted by y

In your case, `awk -F':' '$1 !~ /root/' /etc/passwd` will print all lines, which the first field does **not** match `/root/`, so you have 37 lines.

**`~!` is not an operator.** The expression `'$1 ~! /root/'` does two things:

- `!/root/` : evaluate `$0 !~ /root/` if a line doesn't contain `root`, return `1`
- `$1 ~       !/root/`: I added spaces in between, to make it more clear. Here, we check if `$1` matches the result of the previous step, (`0` or `1`)

`vbirduser1` contains `1`, therefore, it is in the output. If you have other lines, which the first field contains `1` or `0`, they will also be printed in the output.

**But we should avoid using expressions like that in production codes**

Comment: so if the line contains `root`, the `!/root/` will return `0` instead?

Comment: @admin yes  `"something root" !~ /root/` will return `0`

Comment: @admin So both terms that contains `root` AND `0` will return as well as terms that don't contains `root ` and  do contain `1` will return. Both `rootUser0` and `myUser1` will pass this strange test.

Comment: You have two conditions. First you test if the entire line does not contains the word "root": `!/root/`. That returns a `true` or a `false`, which in awk is just a `1` or `0`. Then your second condition hits to test if the first column contains that `1` or `0`. Your confusion may stem from the way you wrote `$1 ~! /root` which makes it seem like `~!` are one operator. Instead it's being interpreted like `$1 ~ (!/root/)`.